How to Unpivot Table and get Column Header-Row Header Range
Like to Unpivot a table and get a string of the Col-Row Headers
Data Sample




Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




Row 1
x






Row 2







Row 3
x

x

x


Row 4







Row 5







Row 6
x

x




Row 7







Row 8

x

x



Row 9







Row 10


x





And Get Results as follows:

Col1 - Row 1
Col1 - Row 3
Col3 - Row 3
Col5 - Row 3
Col1 - Row 6
Col3 - Row 6
Col2 - Row 8
Col4 - Row 8
Col3 - Row 10


EDIT: Custom function
If you want to define it as a custom function, you can use:
F(row_header,col_header,data) ← ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(IF(data="",,col_header&" | "&row_header),1))

And use it as follows:
=F(A2:A,B1:F1,B2:F)


Or within the formula:
=LET(F,LAMBDA(row_header,col_header,data,ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(IF(data="",,col_header&" | "&row_header),1))),
     F(A2:A,B1:F1,B2:F))



Assuming the table is in A1:F with B1:F1 being the header, you can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TOCOL(IF(B2:F="",,B1:F1&","&A2:A),1),","))


Perfect, according to OP's desired output, it could be avoided the SPLIT, and just replace the comma with a dash: =ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(IF(B2:F="",,B1:F1&" - "&A2:A),1))

yeah I wasn't sure whether OP wanted the result in separate columns or not but it's very easy to go from one to the other.

Of course, thanks for your answer! I loved its simplicity!

How would this formula be converted to a lambda() type formula to facilitate replication in other sheets or to include as a Custom Formula.
Thanks.
PS: I Tried using:
" =Lambda(RowHeader,ColHeader,TableData,ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(IF(TableData="",,ColHeader&" | "&RowHeader),1))) (A12:AI,AK1:BK1,AK2:BK) "
But got a recursive calculation error.
